# Скрыть пункт меню в select

Tags: javascript

Нужно скрыть часть пунктов `select`.
То есть, чтобы при выборе "Цветная" скрылись пункты с `value="2"`, а при выборе "Чёрно-белая" - `value="1"`.
Что я делаю не так?

```js
var card_paper = document.getElementById("card_paper");

card_paper.onchange = function() {
  if (card_paper.options[card_paper.selectedIndex].value == '1') {
    var sel = document.getElementById('card_color');
    sel.options[2].setAttribute('disabled', true);
  }
};
```

```css
select option[disabled] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="card_paper">Выберите цветность</label>
<select name="card_paper" id="card_paper" class="form-control">
  <option value="1">Цветная</option>
  <option value="2">Чёрно-белая</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<label for="card_color">Выберите размер модуля</label>
<select name="card_color" id="card_color" class="form-control">
  <!-- Цветная -->
  <option price="878" image="2" value="1">Базовый (11 см2)</option>
  <option price="1587" image="3" value="1">2Б (23 см2)</option>
  <option price="2244" image="4" value="1">3Б (34 см2)</option>
  <option price="2976" image="5" value="1">4Б (48 см2)</option>
  <option price="4380" image="6" value="1">6Б (73 см2)</option>
  <option price="5529" image="7" value="1">8Б (97 см2)</option>
  <option price="6655" image="8" value="1">10Б (121 см2)</option>
  <option price="7738" image="9" value="1">12Б (146 см2)</option>
  <option price="9282" image="10" value="1">15Б (182 см2)</option>
  <option price="9600" image="11" value="1">16Б (192 см2)</option>
  <option price="10829" image="12" value="1">18Б (221 см2)</option>
  <option price="11712" image="13" value="1">20Б (244 см2)</option>
  <option price="12200" image="14" value="1">21Б (260 см2)</option>
  <option price="13340" image="15" value="1">24Б (290 см2)</option>
  <option price="15570" image="16" value="1">28Б (346 см2)</option>
  <option price="16148" image="17" value="1">30Б (367 см2)</option>
  <option price="19092" image="18" value="1">36Б (444 см2)</option>
  <option price="22260" image="19" value="1">42Б (530 см2)</option>
  <option price="41820" image="20" value="1">Первая полоса (1020 см2)</option>
  <option price="42800" image="21" value="1">Целая полоса (1070 см2)</option>
  <!-- Чёрно-белая -->
  <option price="498" image="1" value="2">Минимальный (6,3 см2)</option>
  <option price="781" image="2" value="2">Базовый (11 см2)</option>
  <option price="1472" image="3" value="2">2Б (23 см2)</option>
  <option price="2006" image="4" value="2">3Б (34 см2)</option>
  <option price="2688" image="5" value="2">4Б (48 см2)</option>
  <option price="3942" image="6" value="2">6Б (73 см2)</option>
  <option price="5141" image="7" value="2">8Б (97 см2)</option>
  <option price="6171" image="8" value="2">10Б (121 см2)</option>
  <option price="7300" image="9" value="2">12Б (146 см2)</option>
  <option price="8918" image="10" value="2">15Б (182 см2)</option>
  <option price="9216" image="11" value="2">16Б (192 см2)</option>
  <option price="10387" image="12" value="2">18Б (221 см2)</option>
  <option price="11224" image="13" value="2">20Б (244 см2)</option>
  <option price="11700" image="14" value="2">21Б (260 см2)</option>
  <option price="12760" image="15" value="2">24Б (290 см2)</option>
  <option price="14878" image="16" value="2">28Б (346 см2)</option>
  <option price="15414" image="17" value="2">30Б (367 см2)</option>
  <option price="18204" image="18" value="2">36Б (444 см2)</option>
  <option price="21200" image="19" value="2">42Б (530 см2)</option>
  <option price="39590" image="21" value="2">Целая полоса (1070 см2)</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var card_paper = document.getElementById("card_paper");
var list = document.getElementById("card_color");

card_paper.addEventListener('change', toggleElements);

function toggleElements(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  list.disabled = false;
  
      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list.options[i].value === target.value) {
          list.options[i].disabled = false;
        } 
    
        if (list.options[i].value !== target.value) {
          list.options[i].disabled = true;
          if (list.options[i].selected) {
            list.options[i].selected = false;
          }
        }

      }
  
      if (target.value === "-1") {
        list.disabled = true;
      }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    select option:disabled {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<label for="card_paper">Выберите цветность</label>
<select name="card_paper" id="card_paper" class="form-control">
  <option value="-1">...</option>
  <option value="1">Цветная</option>
  <option value="2">Чёрно-белая</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<label for="card_color">Выберите размер модуля</label>
<select name="card_color" id="card_color" class="form-control" disabled>
  <!-- Цветная -->
  <option price="878" image="2" value="1">Базовый (11 см2)</option>
  <option price="1587" image="3" value="1">2Б (23 см2)</option>
  <option price="2244" image="4" value="1">3Б (34 см2)</option>
  <option price="2976" image="5" value="1">4Б (48 см2)</option>
  <option price="4380" image="6" value="1">6Б (73 см2)</option>
  <option price="5529" image="7" value="1">8Б (97 см2)</option>
  <option price="6655" image="8" value="1">10Б (121 см2)</option>
  <option price="7738" image="9" value="1">12Б (146 см2)</option>
  <option price="9282" image="10" value="1">15Б (182 см2)</option>
  <option price="9600" image="11" value="1">16Б (192 см2)</option>
  <option price="10829" image="12" value="1">18Б (221 см2)</option>
  <option price="11712" image="13" value="1">20Б (244 см2)</option>
  <option price="12200" image="14" value="1">21Б (260 см2)</option>
  <option price="13340" image="15" value="1">24Б (290 см2)</option>
  <option price="15570" image="16" value="1">28Б (346 см2)</option>
  <option price="16148" image="17" value="1">30Б (367 см2)</option>
  <option price="19092" image="18" value="1">36Б (444 см2)</option>
  <option price="22260" image="19" value="1">42Б (530 см2)</option>
  <option price="41820" image="20" value="1">Первая полоса (1020 см2)</option>
  <option price="42800" image="21" value="1">Целая полоса (1070 см2)</option>
  <!-- Чёрно-белая -->
  <option price="498" image="1" value="2">Минимальный (6,3 см2)</option>
  <option price="781" image="2" value="2">Базовый (11 см2)</option>
  <option price="1472" image="3" value="2">2Б (23 см2)</option>
  <option price="2006" image="4" value="2">3Б (34 см2)</option>
  <option price="2688" image="5" value="2">4Б (48 см2)</option>
  <option price="3942" image="6" value="2">6Б (73 см2)</option>
  <option price="5141" image="7" value="2">8Б (97 см2)</option>
  <option price="6171" image="8" value="2">10Б (121 см2)</option>
  <option price="7300" image="9" value="2">12Б (146 см2)</option>
  <option price="8918" image="10" value="2">15Б (182 см2)</option>
  <option price="9216" image="11" value="2">16Б (192 см2)</option>
  <option price="10387" image="12" value="2">18Б (221 см2)</option>
  <option price="11224" image="13" value="2">20Б (244 см2)</option>
  <option price="11700" image="14" value="2">21Б (260 см2)</option>
  <option price="12760" image="15" value="2">24Б (290 см2)</option>
  <option price="14878" image="16" value="2">28Б (346 см2)</option>
  <option price="15414" image="17" value="2">30Б (367 см2)</option>
  <option price="18204" image="18" value="2">36Б (444 см2)</option>
  <option price="21200" image="19" value="2">42Б (530 см2)</option>
  <option price="39590" image="21" value="2">Целая полоса (1070 см2)</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот что получилось с использованием jquery, осталось только при инициализации черно-белые скрывать, но это сам разберешься.

Ссылка на jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/r8jynb8w/3/

```
jQuery.fn.toggleOption = function( show ) {
    jQuery( this ).toggle( show );
    if( show ) {
        if( jQuery( this ).parent( 'span.toggleOption' ).length )
            jQuery( this ).unwrap( );
    } else {
        if( jQuery( this ).parent( 'span.toggleOption' ).length == 0 )
            jQuery( this ).wrap( '<span class="toggleOption" style="display: none;" />' );
    }
};

var card_paper = $('#card_paper');
var card_color = $('#card_color');

card_paper.change(function(event){
    var type = $(event.target).val();
  $('#card_color option').each(function(id, option){
    option = $(option);
    if(option.attr('value')==type){
        option.toggleOption(true);
    }else{
        option.toggleOption(false);
    }
  })
});
```